# Remove part of url, but keep extension

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite

All of my websites are generated in the following pattern:

```
http://www.example.com/category/xyz/article---12345.html
```

I want to use mod_rewrite to remove the part "---12345", where the three minuses are always there, but the amount of numbers varies from 3 to 7.
The html shoul stay there so that the urls look like that:

```
http://www.example.com/category/xyz/article.html
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Isn't the job of the numbers to distinguish between unique articles?

Comment: When users type `http://www.example.com/category/xyz/article.html` in their address bar, which page do you want to show them?

Comment: If you want cleaner urls, you could redirect `http://www.example.com/category/xyz/article/xxxxx` to `http://www.example.com/category/xyz/article---xxxxx.html`

Comment: I think u are retiring the articles using that numbers section then you can change the stucture of the url http://www.example.com/category/xyz/article---12345.html to http://www.example.com/category/xyz/12345/article.html

Comment: the numbers are not referring to different article, each article has it's own url independent of the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule assumes that the html file you are requesting doesn't exist and will redirect them to the new html file name. It will do this for any .html file and not just those called "article".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ---
RewriteRule ^(.*)---(.*)$ "/$1.html" [R=301]
```

Things to note:
If the original .html file exists remove the first two RewriteCond rules.
If you don't want the address bar to change then replace [R=301] with [L]

Answer (score 0):

File: `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xyz/article---([0-9]{3,7}).html /xyz/article.html
```

Problem: you have to have one `.htaccess` in every folder where the `article---xxxxxx.html` is